# mgtwitterengine and oauth 401 error: Boggled

Tags: oauth, twitter, xcode3.2, http-status-code-401, mgtwitterengine

OK... so here is my code:

```
twitterEngine = [[MGTwitterEngine alloc] initWithDelegate:self];    
    [twitterEngine setConsumerKey:CONSUMER_KEY secret:CONSUMER_SECRET];
    accessToken = [twitterEngine getXAuthAccessTokenForUsername:profile.twitterUserId password:profile.twitterPassword];
    NSLog(@"Access token: %@", accessToken);
```

the console shows the access token returned just fine (so it seems to work)
eg. Access token: C8A24515-0F11-4B5A-8813-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

but instead of accessTokenReceived method being called next on my delegate, it calls requestFailed with a 401.  How can I be getting a 401 unauthorized and getting an access token back from the method call?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue... for anyone else that has this problem... Getting your app approved for OAuth is only part of the process.  Although it looks like you are done and the twitter page gives you your key and secret... there is one not-quite-so-easy-to-find next step.  You must send an email to api@twitter.com and ask them to actually enable it.

That was fun figuring out.  :)

Answer (score 2):

xAuth, the process for exchanging a login and password for an access token, is a privilege for applications that verifiably meet Twitter's criteria: desktop or mobile applications that are otherwise unable to provide the entire three-legged OAuth flow. Out-of-band OAuth and custom URI schemes are still preferred over xAuth.

If you've exhausted other OAuth implementations and want to use xAuth, you can contact Twitter through api@twitter.com from an email address directly associated with the account owning the application. Include full details about your application, its user base, links to screenshots of it in action, and a detailed description on why this form of authorization is appropriate for your application. Inquires for xAuth are considered on a case-by-case basis and will not be granted to all applicants.

Implementors of xAuth must not store logins and passwords within their applications -- this is not a drop-in replacement for basic auth or a way to avoid implementing OAuth authentication.